# Credit Card authorization using Epicor Web service

Tags: web-services, epicorerp

We are using order web service to submit order from our web application to Epicor. We are facing issue for credit card authorization. We are sending all required credit card details from the web service and all the details are getting populated in Epicor Sales Order Entry => Hearder => Credit Card but when we are clicking on Authorize button its showing "Invalid Account Number".

We also manually done the credit card entry in Epicor for same credit card and itsauthorizes in this case.

We are not sure do we need to send any other information with while submitting order so that it will authorize the credit card We tried using test credit card in Epicor i.e Visa 4111111111111111

Comment: Not quite programming related. You might want to give Epicor support a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart the Epicor Authorization Lite Service, along with the Thre Secure Daata Web Services.  This is normally on the APP Server.  Also check in Order header -> billing -> Credit Card to see if it is stroing the credit card after the credit card entry.